# How do I create an object containing each letter of a data attribute as well as the position of that letter of the alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently doing a coding challenge where I have to write a jQuery function to get the value of the data parameter of each div below, and create an object containing each letter as well as the position of that letter of the alphabet.

```html
<div class="foo" data-widget="bar">This</div>
<div class="foo" data-widget="baz">That</div>
```

The output should be:

```
This: {"b":"2", "a":"1", "r":"18"}
That: {"b":"2", "a":"1", "z":"26"}
```

So far this is what I have:

```
var allAttributes = $('.foo').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('data-widget');
}).get();

console.log(allAttributes);

//this function finds the numerical position of the letters in a string
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
var alphabetPosition = text => 
  text.split('').map(x => alphabet.indexOf(x) + 1);
```

Comment: It's not a challenge if someone else answers it for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct the object for each `div`, you can get the item's `data-widget` attribute value, split into an array of characters, map through each and construct an array containing the letter and its index in `alphabet`, then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert into an object.

```js
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');

const obj = {}

$('.foo').each(function(){
  obj[this.textContent] = Object.fromEntries(this.dataset.widget.split('').map(e => [e, alphabet.indexOf(e) + 1]))
})

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" data-widget="bar">This</div>
<div class="foo" data-widget="baz">That</div>
```

Comment: var alphabet = "_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(''); ><

Comment: @bZezzz What do you mean?

Comment: @Spectric as a way to offset the index, thus the count is not 0 based.

Comment: @Twisty doesn't he do that in the each function?  "alphabet.indexOf(e) + 1"

Comment: @Velocibadgery yes, he does, and he can "normalize" it in the way that was suggested if he wants. I read it as a suggestion, thats all.

Comment: Well, OP.  If you accept the suggestion, make sure you remove the offset from the each function first.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var myText = {};

  function charPos(c) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
    return alphabet.indexOf(c) + 1;
  }

  function wordDetails(w) {
    var r = {};
    $.each(w.split(""), function(i, c) {
      r[c] = charPos(c.toString());
    });
    return r;
  }

  $(".foo").each(function(i, el) {
    myText[$(el).text().trim()] = wordDetails($(el).data("widget"));
  });
  console.log(myText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" data-widget="bar">This</div>
<div class="foo" data-widget="baz">That</div>
```

Result:

```
{
  "This": {
    "b": 2,
    "a": 1,
    "r": 18
  },
  "That": {
    "b": 2,
    "a": 1,
    "z": 26
  }
}
```

If you want to minimize it:

```js
$(function() {
  var myText = {};

  $(".foo").each(function(i, el) {
    var obj = {};
    $.each($(el).data("widget").split(""), function() {
      obj[this] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('').indexOf(this.toString()) + 1;
    });
    myText[$(el).text().trim()] = obj;
  });

  console.log(myText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" data-widget="bar">This</div>
<div class="foo" data-widget="baz">That</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I accept your challenge, however after completing it I realized you did say JQuery and this solution is just Javascript.

Check out my solution here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/agilecollab/pen/yLobPqp?editors=1111)

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");
let alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
let result = {};
Array.from(elements).map(e => {
  let key = e.innerText;
  let value = {};
  let data = e.dataset.widget.split('');
  data.map( c => value[c] = alph.indexOf(c) + 1 );
  result[key] = value;
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that...
with the help of [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const
  alphabet = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
, result =
    Array
    .from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo'))
    .reduce( (res,e) => 
      {
      res[e.textContent] = 
        [...e.dataset.widget]
        .reduce( (r,c) =>
          (r[c] = alphabet.indexOf(c).toString(10), r )
        ,{})
      return res
      },{})
 
const // show result
  rpl  = [[`"`,`'`],[`}`,` }`],[`{`,`{ `],[`:`,`: `],[`},`,`}\n,`],[`,`,`, `],[`} }`,`}\n}`]]
, clog = s => rpl.reduce((r,[x,y])=>r.replaceAll(x,y),s)

console.log( clog(JSON.stringify(result)) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<div class="foo" data-widget="bar">This</div>
<div class="foo" data-widget="baz">That</div>
```